# node.js call a perl script and get stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to use node.js to call a perl script as a process and read back stdout line by line?

I pretty sure with normal javascript this is usually not possible but a server side script using node.js it would seem to make some sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use node's built-in [`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn) command for child process execution, and [`carrier`](https://github.com/pgte/carrier) to handle line-by-line processing of `stdout`:

Install:

```
$ npm install carrier
```

Code:

```
var util    = require('util'),
    spawn   = require('child_process').spawn,
    carrier = require('carrier'),
    pl_proc = spawn('perl', ['script.pl']),
    my_carrier;

my_carrier = carrier.carry(pl_proc.stdout);

my_carrier.on('line', function(line) {
  // Do stuff...
  console.log('line: ' + line);
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, look into spawn/exec.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/child_processes.html

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("perl someperl.pl", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    /* do something */
});
```

I am not sure why you wouldn't just do it in node.

Comment: Also note that this gives you back stdout (and stderr) in one big blob, and not line by line.  You'll need to split the output on the newline character if that's very important to you.

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't do what exactly?  Use a perl script?  A pretty straightforward example would be a perl module that would be difficult or time-consuming rewrite in node.